# Swift: How to get the position of SKShapeNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpath, skshapenode

I'm having trouble with SKShapeNode's position. I'm storing a path from user touch of screen. Then I create a polygon of that and put it into `pathOfShape`variable. I create SKShapeNode of that path and everything works fine. I get the user drawn polygon neatly drawn on screen.

However I would like to add more stuff on the polygon. For some reason I cannot get the position of the SKShapeNode. Instead if I try to use `position` attribute, it points to x:0.0, y:0.0 like below. What's going one here? How can I get the actual `position` of my SKShapeNode?

```
var pathOfShape = CGPathCreateMutable()                       
//path of polygon added here to pathOfShape
var shapeNode = SKShapeNode()
shapeNode.path = pathOfShape 
shapeNode.name = "shape"
self.addChild(shapeNode)

let node1 = self.childNodeWithName("shape")
print(node1?.position)
```

results to `Optional((0.0, 0.0))`

Comment: Since you did not change the `position` property of the shape, it's still at the default value, (0, 0). Adding a `CGPath` to the shape does not change its position. The path is rendered relative to (0, 0).

Comment: @0x141E But the SKShapeNode is not in 0,0 but exactly where the user draw it

Comment: The path is drawn _relative_ to (0, 0). The points in the polygon can have any value (in the scene) but the _origin_ of the `CGPath` is the position of the shape node.

Comment: @0x141E So inorder to get the position of the shape, I have to get it from the path?

Comment: You can save the points of the polygon in an array as the user taps on the screen and then compute the centroid of the points in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you make a `CGPath`, for example a triangle:

```
var pathOfShape = CGPathCreateMutable()
let center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x, center.y)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x + 50, center.y + 50)
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x + 50, center.y + 50)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x - 50, center.y + 50)
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x - 50, center.y + 50)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x - 50, center.y - 50)
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x - 50, center.y - 50)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathOfShape, nil, center.x, center.y)
CGPathCloseSubpath(pathOfShape)
```

[image]

And you decide to create a `SKShapeNode` based from this path:

```
let shape = SKShapeNode(path: pathOfShape)
```

You could ask to get the center of this shape:

```
let center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(shape.frame),CGRectGetMidY(shape.frame))
```

The correct position is always (0.0, 0.0) but almost you know where is your shape.